# Gmail removes the src attribute of img tag

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I have red many posts around google and stackoverflow. Seems like none of them worked for me. And many people can't figure it out. Is it really so hard to put html inline image and if it's possible in 2019, how should we do it?

```
<img src="https://example.com/image.png" alt="myimage">
```

is show as only

```
<img alt="myimage">
```

I am using PHPMailer and dont need to attach it. Is there a solution for this ? Thank you!

Comment: Gmail is terrible in many respects – and this is one of the ways. You may have more luck with embedded images (and corresponding `cid` identifiers to reference them from your HTML) or `data` URLs, but those methods are of course much less efficient.

Comment: External images get filtered out by default, so that the requests they would cause can not be used to determine when / that a mail is read by the recipient (little thing called _privacy_.) The recipient has the option to view the mails with those external images - but they have to actively trigger that. If you want to send images that always get shown - then you need to actually _inline_ them directly into the mail. (What you are doing with the above, is not “inlining”.)

Comment: @Toma Show us your PHP code

Answer (score -1):

Php Mailer email image you can use src tag but keep that in mind you have to add public link for the src like : http://example.com/image.png not project image path.

Comment: That's not what's being asked here - images are in the original source message, but gmail is removing them.